# Find value of $ S = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!(n+2)} $

Tags: integration, derivatives, taylor-expansion, exponential-function

I am stuck on this question. Could someone help me?

$$ \text{Find value of } S = \displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \cfrac{1}{n!(n+2)} $$

I am supposed to show that $ S = 1 $ in two ways: 
1) Integrate the taylor series of $ xe^x $ 
2) Differentiate the taylor series of $ \frac{e^{x-1}}{x} $

For (1), I tried to using the fact that the taylor series of
$ e^x = \displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n!} $

Now, multiplying $ x $ into the taylor series gives:
$$ xe^x = \displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \cfrac{x^{n+1}}{n!} $$

Integrating this yields the following:

$$ \begin{align} \int_0^x xe^x &= \displaystyle\int_0^x\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \cfrac{x^{n+1}}{n!} \\ &= \displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \cfrac{x^{n+2}}{n!(n+2)} \end{align} $$

I am not sure how to cary on from here.

For (2), I am not sure how to find the taylor series for $ \frac{(e^x - 1)}{x} $

Is anyone able to assist me?

Comment: Well, you put $x=1$ in your last equation there.

Comment: For (2) you first have $\frac{e^{x-1}}{2}$, and second you have $\frac{e^x-1}{2}$. Which is it?

Comment: @Carl Schildkraut. My bad. I corrected the typo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For (1), you need to be careful with using $x$ as your dummy variable: try

$$\int_0^t xe^x\ dx = \int_0^t \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{n+1}}{n!}\ dx$$

$$ = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \int_0^t\frac{x^{n+1}}{n!}\ dx$$

$$ = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{n+2}}{n!(n+2)}\bigg|_0^t$$

$$ = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{t^{n+2}}{n!(n+2)}$$

At $t=1$, this equals our desired sum. We then evaluate the integral

$$\int_0^1 xe^x\ dx$$

which can be done with integration by parts.

For (2), we can simply use that the Taylor Series of $e^x$ is

$$e^x = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n!}$$

$$e^x-1 = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n!}$$

$$\frac{e^x-1}{x} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^{n-1}}{n!} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{(n+1)!}$$

and then differentiate, and set $x=1$ as you did before.

Comment: I understand that integrating from 0 to 1 will give the sum of the function. But how does differentiating give the sum?

Comment: @LanceHAOH Try differentiating it. What do you get?

Comment: I got $ \frac{nx^{n-1}}{(n+1)!} $ I tried to manipulate the denominator but  I cannot get it to look like the equation $ S $. Hence, this seems to lead to nowhere.

Comment: @LanceHAOH Try factoring $(n+1)!$ as $(n-1)!n(n+1)$, and performing the change of variables $n\to n+1$.

Comment: This will yield $ \sum_{n=-1}^{\infty} \frac{x^{n}}{(n+2)(n!)} $ But $ n = -1 $ as the starting point doesn't make sense.

Comment: No it doesn't. However, the lowest term you get (from originally $n=0$) is constant, so you get $0$, not $\frac{1}{x}$, when you differentiate it.

Answer (score 0):

Observe
\begin{align}
\int^1_0 xe^x\ dx = \sum^\infty_{n=0} \int^1_0\frac{x^{n+1}}{n!}\ dx = \sum^\infty_{n=0} \frac{1}{n!(n+2)}
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Another way $$S = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \cfrac{1}{n!(n+2)}\\S = \displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \cfrac{1}{n!(n+2)}\times \frac{n+1}{n+1}\\=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \cfrac{n+1}{(n+2)!}\\=
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \cfrac{(n+2)-1}{(n+2)!}\\=
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \cfrac{n+2}{(n+2)!}-\cfrac{1}{(n+2)!}\\=
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \cfrac{1}{(n+1)!}-\cfrac{1}{(n+2)!}\\=
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} f(n)-f(n+1)\\=
\frac{1}{(0+1)!}-\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{(n+2)!}\\=1-0
$$